# ldap_search function returns errorcode 10 using c++ Win32 api?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, active-directory, ldap

i am using ldap functions to get user attributes value using win32 api.

the user name is `arun`.

in ldap_functions like init,set_options,connect,bind is succeed.but ldap search function is returned error code 10.

here my code

```
errorCode = ldap_search_s(
                    pLdapConnection,    // Session handle
                    pMyDN,              // DN to start search
                    LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE, // Scope  LDAP_SCOPE_BASE LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE
                    pMyFilter,          // Filter
                    NULL,               // Retrieve list of attributes
                    0,                  // Get both attributes and values
                    &pSearchResult);
```

in `pMyDN` specified `"DC=SANJU,DC=CO,DC=IN"...

the return code 10 gives error is `LDAP_REFERRAL`.but i cant get it.

But i put `pMyDN` value into `"OU=Marketing,DC=SANJU,DC=CO,DC=IN"`

Now,search function succeed,So what is the problem?

i need this function without using OU,
can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LDAP_REFERRAL: sent by Directory Server if the given base DN is an entry not handled by the current server and if the referral URL identifies a different server to handle the entry.

Comment: @ Saddam :k.now what will i do,i want to search without OU specified?

Comment: you can put pMyDN ad DC=SANJU,DC=CO,DC=IN and search which should give you the result, and it wont make a difference from speed point of view  if you have from small to medium tree, if you got a results, this means that the DN for you OU is wrong

Answer (score 1):

whether DNS and AD in different URL(IP) without trusted rule,this problem will occured.

Answer (score 0):

LDAP response do not use `error codes`, they use `result codes` - so called because non-zero responses aren't necessarily errors. 10 is a case in point, it's a referral. The referral will contain information about the server which can process the request. If a directory proxy server is not in place to follow the referral, the LDAP client must follow the referral for itself.

Compare operation responses also use result codes to transmit the result of a compare.